# 301 redirect -new link structure of website

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301, redirect

i am converting an old zencart site to opencart with new design. every thing is done, i have also enabled SEF urls in opencart so my opencart links look like

```
http://www.mysite.com/product/cat1/subcat/product-name-1/
```

here is the .htaccess code used by OpenCart

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

the problem is that i want to 301 redirect old zencart urls to new opencart urls on the same domain for SEO purposes.

i tried somple 301 redirect .htaccess code but it did not work

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_2&products_id=1 /product/cat1/subcat/product-name-1/
```

i also tried url rewriting but could not figure it our. so i am looking for best way to redirect the old url to new url. i have about 300+ links to redirect

Comment: List some URLs that you want to redirect and the paths that you want to refer.

Comment: in format, with ::: as separator   
old url:::new url  

/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_2&products_id=1:::/product/show-panels/camaro/67-69/1-piece-show-panel-no-engraving/  

/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_3&products_id=16:::/product/show-panels/camaro/70-81/show-panel-no-engraving/  

/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_9&products_id=54:::/product/show-panels/chevelle/68-69/show-panel-no-engraving/

Comment: _/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_4&products_id=24:::product/show-panels/camaro/2010-2012/2010-show-panel/_  
**/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_5&products_id=25:::product/show-panels/chevelle/64/show-panel-no-engraving/**  
`/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_11&products_id=68:::product/show-panels/chevy-and-gmc-trucks/67-68/`  
/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_23&products_id=113:::product/show-panels/mustang/69-70/  

`/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_26&products_id=112:::product/show-panels/dodge-charger/2005-2008/`